# Defining NSLayoutConstraints to include rectangles inside a view

Tags: objective-c, autolayout

I have a input data in a format of:

```
[
  {{0,0}, {0.3, 0.8}},
  {{0.4, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.2}}
]
```

So basically they're the string representation of `CGRect`s that are contained in a `1x1` rectangle.

Now I need to display them on the screen, inside a `UIView` thats dimensions are calculated using Auto Layout. So I wanted to translate those into `NSLayoutConstraints`, so the inside rectangles would resize as their superview resizes.

I can set the width and height of the subviews pretty easily. In a loop over all the rects from the array I create a new `UIView`:

```
CGRect r = CGRectFromString(rectString)
UIView *rect = [[UIView alloc] init];
[superview addSubview:rect];
NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint 
          constraintWithItem: rect
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
          relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem: superview
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
          multiplier: r.size.width
          constant:0];
[superview addConstraint:width];
```

The same goes to height.

But when I want to set the `x` and `y` coordinates of those rectangles to be based on the width and height of their superview, I get an error.

My code:

```
NSLayoutConstraint * left = [NSLayoutConstraint 
                                             constraintWithItem: rect
                                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                      relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem: superview
                                                      attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier: r.origin.x
                                                       constant: 0];
[superview addConstraint: left];
```

If my `r.origin.x` is `0`, the error I get is: `A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs`.

In other cases (when it's not `0`), the error reads: `Invalid pairing of layout attributes`. Seems like I can't mix `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` and `NSLayoutAttributeWidth`.

Is there any way to lay out the subviews like that, without creating a complex subviews structure inside (like, adding a special "spacing" view between Left/Top edges of the superview and the top-left corner of my rectangle)?

Comment: Could you draft what you want to achieve to make it clear? Regarding constraints left and width making equal makes no sense - what that would mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constraining `Left` to `Width` with a multiplier and `Right` to `Height` with a multiplier, I would suggest constraining `Right` to `Right` with a multiplier of `origin.x + size.width` and `Bottom` to `Bottom` with a multiplier of `origin.y + size.height`.

Here is an implementation in Swift which demonstrates with your rectangle values.  Using Swift allows me to show the results in a Playground.

```
let superview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
superview.backgroundColor = .yellowColor()

let rectStrings = ["{{0,0}, {0.3, 0.8}}", "{{0.4, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.2}}"]
let colors: [UIColor] = [.blueColor(), .redColor()]

for i in 0 ..< rectStrings.count {
    let r = CGRectFromString(rectStrings[i])

    let rect = UIView()
    rect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    rect.backgroundColor = colors[i]
    superview.addSubview(rect)

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: rect, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview,
        attribute: .Width, multiplier: r.size.width, constant: 0).active = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: rect, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview,
        attribute: .Height, multiplier: r.size.height, constant: 0).active = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: rect, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview,
        attribute: .Right, multiplier: r.origin.x + r.size.width, constant: 0).active = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: rect, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview,
        attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: r.origin.y + r.size.height, constant: 0).active = true
}

superview.layoutIfNeeded()
```

---

Here it is running in a Swift Playground:

[image: Playground demonstration of rectangle constraints]

---

Here's the equivalent in Objective-C.  `superview` is an `IBOutlet` to a view that is laid out in the Storyboard:

```
NSArray *rectStrings = @[@"{{0,0}, {0.3, 0.8}}", @"{{0.4, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.2}}"];
NSArray *colors = @[[UIColor blueColor], [UIColor redColor]];

for (int i = 0; i < rectStrings.count; i++) {
    CGRect r = CGRectFromString(rectStrings[i]);

    UIView *rect = [[UIView alloc] init];

    rect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    rect.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    [self.superview addSubview: rect];

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: rect
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: self.superview
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                multiplier: r.size.width
                                  constant: 0].active = YES;

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: rect
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: self.superview
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                multiplier: r.size.height
                                  constant: 0].active = YES;

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: rect
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: self.superview
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                multiplier: r.origin.x + r.size.width
                                  constant: 0].active = YES;

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: rect
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem: self.superview
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                multiplier: r.origin.y + r.size.height
                                  constant: 0].active = YES;
}

[self.superview layoutIfNeeded];
```

---

This answer is based upon rectangle values in a 1x1 rectangle as stated in your question.  To make this work with any sized rectangle, simply divide by the width and height of that rectangle.

For instance, if your rectangles were:

```
let rectStrings = ["{{0,0}, {3.0, 8.0}}", "{{4.0, 2.0}, {3.0, 2.0}}"]
```

and the size of your rectangle is 10 wide by 20 high, then you'd just scale the values by dividing by the width and height.

The width, height, right, and bottom multipliers would be:

```
r.size.width / 10.0
r.size.height / 20.0
(r.origin.x + r.size.width) / 10.0
(r.origin.y + r.size.height) / 20.0
```

Comment: It's all good, but isn't the solution tied to a 1x1 rect? It uses the absolute values of the rect origin and size in the constraints...

Comment: @kender, see the updated answer.  You just need to scale the multipliers if you have a rect that isn't 1x1.

Comment: But then if my size is also calculated using auto layout...? Would that work?

Comment: The size of your view is calculated using auto layout.  The rectangle I'm talking about is the template that give the relative sizes of the sub rectangles.  As auto layout resizes your view, the subviews would grow proportionally.